# Docker Linux Mounted code is RO

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file to build me 2 services. It starts up and runs perfectly. The problem is that if I execute an ember command in the container, it creates the files but when I edited them in VS code and hit save, I get permission denied. How can I fix this?

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  ember-bower_components:
  ember-node_modules:

services:
  ember:
    build: .
    container_name: cf2-ember
    ports:
      - 7357:7357
      - 4200:4200
      - 9222:9222
      - 49152:49152
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - ember-bower_components:/myapp/bower_components
      - ember-node_modules:/myapp/node_modules
      - ./docker/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    tmpfs:
      - /myapp/tmp
    environment:
      - APIM_HOST=CHANGEME
      - APIM_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY=CHANGEME
    command: ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.12.1-alpine
    container_name: cf2-nginx
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    depends_on:
      - ember
    volumes:
      - ./docker/default.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
      - ./dist:/usr/share/nginx/html:delegated
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=localhost
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Comment: What are the permissions on those files? Can't you change them?

Comment: @Nowhereman they are owned by root because that is what docker is doing. That is going to be pretty bad if every time I create a new file I need to execute a chown on them

Comment: There is nothing special about how Docker handles file ownership and permissions.  Just like outside of Docker, files will be owned by whatever user created them.  If you're running as `root`, they will be owned by `root`.  If you don't want them owned by `root`, then `chown` them, or run as another user id.

Answer (score 1):

`` docker run -u `id -u`:`id -g` <image name> ``

Or in your case using `docker-compose`:

`` docker-compose run -u `id -u`:`id -g` <service name> ``

This generates files inside the container on a mounted volume as the current user without having to `chown` afterwards.

The `-u` flag enables you to specify the `user:group` to run the container as.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run the container as some other user than root, you can always set default ACLs on the directory so that you can still access the files.

On Linux, that would be with:

```
$ setfacl -Rdm u:myusername:rw ./dist
```